# Implicitly decorate the methods exposed by an interface for intellisence

Tags: c#, interface, intellisense

I have a trivial problem, yet I don't seem to be able to come up with a solution:

```
public interface ISimpleInterface
{
    String GetDayOfWeek();
    String GetLocalTime();
    // a few more hundreds of those
}

public class MyClass : ISimpleInterface, IVeryComplexInterface
{
   // implementations go here
}

MyClass mc = new MyClass();
var day = mc.GetDayOfWeek();
```

So what I would like to do is when I edit my code in Visual Studio and get the point of `mc.` where hundreds of methods will show up, to be able to tell (via IntelliSense maybe) whether each method is defined by `ISimpleInterface` or `IVeryComplexInterface`.

I know I can categorize the results in `mc.` and expose them over an extra layer (e.g. `mc.SimpleMethods.GetDayOfWeek()`) but this is not what I am trying to achieve here.

Ideally I would like to decorate each interface with a short string description which would then show up in IntellliSense and would be common for all methods of this interface (such as "This method belongs to ISimpleInterface").

Is there any obvious way to do that?

Comment: Where in intellisense do you want it to show up? In the tooltip?

Comment: @Cameron really anywhere but yes, tooltip would be great.

Comment: Btw, this isn't a trivial problem :)

Comment: @ErikPhilips lol it seems it's not that trivial at the end of the day

Comment: Changing a tire isn't trivial at the end of the day but, if one isn't prepared, can require a tow truck.

Answer (score 3):

You can add documentation comments to each method so you can have better information about each call and you can put interface name into description

```
public interface ISimpleInterface
{
   /// <summary>As part of ISimpleInterface this method returns... </summary> 
   String GetDayOfWeek();
```

Sometimes just using variable of correct type may be enough:

```
 ISimpleInterface mc = new MyClass();
```

Comment: There are hundreds of methods in each of those interfaces, this is why I'm looking for a more generic approach such as: give the same description to all hundreds of methods in there just to know where they're coming from.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I think of doing this would be to cast your object to that interface :

```
var simpleInterface = ((ISimpleInterface)mc);
// access your object
```

[image]

There might be something else I'm unaware of, though ...

Answer (score 1):

You can also decorate your methods with documentation:

[image]

```
<#@ template debug="true" hostspecific="true" language="C#" #>
<#@ output extension=".vsdocs.cs" #>

<#@ assembly name="EnvDTE" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>

<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ import namespace="Microsoft.CSharp" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.CodeDom.Compiler" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Reflection" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.CodeDom.Compiler" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Reflection" #>

<#
//System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();

// Setup Environment
var dte = (EnvDTE.DTE)((IServiceProvider)Host).GetService(typeof(EnvDTE.DTE));
var project = dte.Solution.FindProjectItem(Host.TemplateFile).ContainingProject;

string path = this.Host.ResolvePath("");
string binpath = Path.Combine(path, "bin");

// Setup Loading File
string IBarCs = Path.Combine(path, "IBar.cs");
string IBarDll = Path.Combine(binpath, "IBar.Dll");
string IBarName = "ConsoleApplication10.IBar";

// Compile File to Temporary DLL
var cProvider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp");

CompilerParameters cp = new CompilerParameters();
cp.GenerateExecutable = false;
cp.OutputAssembly = IBarDll;

CompilerResults cr = cProvider.CompileAssemblyFromFile(cp, IBarCs);

if(cr.Errors.Count > 0)
{
    // Display compilation errors.
    WriteLine("// Errors building {0} into {1}",  IBarCs, cr.PathToAssembly);
    foreach(CompilerError ce in cr.Errors)
    {
        WriteLine("//  {0}", ce.ToString());
    }
}

// Load File for Reflection
var ibar = Assembly.LoadFile(IBarDll);

var iBarType = ibar.GetType(IBarName);
    WriteLine("// " + iBarType.ToString());

var methods = iBarType.GetMethods().ToList();

foreach (var method in methods)
{
    WriteLine("// " + method);
}

#>

// Empty File
```

Comment: How can I apply the same documentation to all hundreds' of methods described in each interface without having to do this for every single method?

Comment: You can use a T4 templates to do it automatically to all your classes if you wanted (or any subset).

Comment: Is this what you're referring to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx ?

Comment: Yes, image a class that at design-time can execute and has access to all your source code, and can do anything to your source code (can be very dangerous too).

Comment: So in other words you suggest I shouldn't use them :)

Comment: Just like anything else, use source control.  If you are writing program to change source, a single mis-step could delete the contents of your file.  I would also say that to anyone who uses [System.IO.File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx).

Comment: I added a huge start to the T4 templating stuff, hope it helps.

Comment: Oh wow, thank you for taking the time to add this bunch of info! +1

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
MyClass mc = new MyClass();
var day = mc.SimpleMethods.GetDayOfWeek();
var anyOtherThing = mc.SimpleMethods.GetAnyOtherThing();
```

Achieved by:

```
public class MySimpleClass : ISimpleInterface
{
   // implementations go here
}

public class MyVeryComplexClass : ISimpleInterface
{
   // implementations go here
}

public class MyClass
{
    public MySimpleClass SimpleMethods = new MySimpleClass();
    public MyVeryComplexClass ComplexMethods = new MyVeryComplexClass();
}
```

This way `MyClass` is a kind of an [aggregate](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/DDD_Aggregate.html), containing smaller and more specialized classes. You may also achieve greater [Single Responsability Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) by doing it.

*Although the names `SimpleMethods` and `ComplexMethods` could be better.*